# db.createView() by matching and comparing two tables in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I would like to createView by comparing and grouping two table in mongodb.

```
table1
{id: 1, item: 'apple', house: 'A'},
{id: 2, item: 'apple', house: 'A'},
{id: 3, item: 'apple', house: 'B'},
{id: 4, item: 'banana', house: 'B'},
{id: 5, item: 'banana', house: 'C'},
{id: 6, item: 'pear', house: 'A'},
{id: 7, item: 'pear', house: 'B'},
{id: 8, item: 'pear', house: 'A'},
{id: 9, item: 'pear', house: 'C'},
```

And in table 2, I need to compare and match

```
table2
{id: 1, fruits: 'apple', type: 'important'},
{id: 2, fruits: 'banana', type: 'important'},
{id: 3, fruits: 'pear', type: 'notImportant'},
```

The result I want to get:

```
houses
{id: 1, house: 'A', totalItem: 4, noOfImportant: 2 },
{id: 2, house: 'B', totalItem: 2, noOfImportant: 2},
{id: 3, house: 'C', totalItem: 2, noOfImportant: 1},
```

I have tried:

```
db.createView(
'houses',
'table1',
    [
        {$lookup: { from: 'table2', localField: 'fruits', foreignField: 'item', as: 'fruits'}},
        {
            '$group': {
                        house: '$house',
                        totalItem: {$sum:1},
                        noOfImportant: {$sum:'$table2.notImpotant'},
                      }
        },

    ]
)
```

but I can't seem to get any thing out. please help me. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$lookup` stage will return an array, even if it only finds a single matching document.

You can use the `$arrayElemAt` operator to pick out the first element, or you could simply `$unwind` the result.

Either way, it looks like there was a typo in your group: `noOfImportant: {$sum:'$table2.notImpotant'},` - there doesn't appear to be a field named "table2", I suspect you meant to check the `type` field of the `fruits` document.

The `$group` stage requires that there be an explicitly defined `_id` field, if you need that field to be called `house` you can to that afterward with projection.
Since the type field is not numeric, you would need to use `$cond` in order to count them up.

```
db.createView(
    'houses',
    'table1',
    [
        {$lookup: { 
                   from: 'table2', 
                   localField: 'item', 
                   foreignField: 'fruits', 
                   as: 'fruits'
        }},
        {$unwind: {
                    path: '$fruits',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }},
        {$group: {
                    _id: '$house',
                    totalItem: {$sum:1},
                    noOfImportant: {
                                    $sum:{
                                          $cond:{
                                            if:{$eq:['$fruits.type', 'important']},
                                            then: 1,
                                            else: 0
                                          }
                                    }
                    },
        }},
        {$addFields: { house: "$_id" }},
        {$project: { _id: 0 }}
    ]
)
```

The `aggregate` functions returns much more descriptive error messages.  You should test the pipeline prior to creating the view.

Here is a [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/btQ62qFCq41) that shows this pipeline in action.

Comment: is it possible to create a collection instead of a view? if so, how? replacing View with collection?

Comment: Run the aggregation with an `$out` stage to write the results to a collection.